# Unable to create VM from existing template using powershell

Tags: azure-powershell

I am getting below error message when creating VM from existing parameter.json and template.json file.

Code    : InvalidDeploymentParameterValue
Message : The value of deployment parameter 'publicIPAddresses_azuse2qaautovm2_ip_name' is null. Please specify the 
          value or use the parameter reference. See https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a value for that parameter (in a parameters file) `publicIPAddresses_azuse2qaautovm2_ip_name` or provide a default value for that parameter.

Comment: Can we assign a default value to dynamically created IP addresses

Comment: no, this is not possible. you can create an Ip address and get it value and set it to static so it doesnt change. thats about it.